# Error Property 'x' does not exist on type 'y[]' in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to render the object exple using *ngFor directive but i have got the error mentioned erlier.
the code is as follow:

```
this.exple=[
      // first user 
      { 
        firstName: 'Msaddak',
        lastName: 'Rouabeh',
        completeAdress: [
          {
            city: 'Gafsa',
            neighborhood: 'Cité Hached Lalla',
          },
          {
            city: 'Monastir',
            neighborhood: 'Skanes',
          }],
        
      },
      // Second user
      {
        firstName: 'Houssem',
        lastName: 'Ilahi',
        completeAdress: [
          {
            city: 'Tunis',
            neighborhood: 'Bardoo',
          },
          {
            city: 'Nabeul',
            neighborhood: 'Mrezka',
          }],
            
      }


    ]
```

The command used for rendering:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of exple.completeAdress"> {{item.city}} </div>
```

{{item.city}} didn't work either.

Comment: You need two levels of `*ngFor*`. First level iterates `exple`. Second level iterates  the address from each item in `exple` array.

Answer (score 0):

`exple` is an array. You cannot access `completeAdress`  of the array, but rather of each item of the array.

Instead you should do

```
<div *ngFor="let item of exple">
    <div *ngFor="let addressItem of item.completeAdress"> {{addressItem.city}} </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to access the array inside an array in one step.

Below you can see that while iterating over the users you then can iterate over the addresses

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of exple"> 
    {{user.firstName}}
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let address of user.completeAdress">
        {{address.city}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to only show the addresses of 1 user you have to select that user by the index:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let address of exple[0].completeAdress">
    {{ address.city }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will show the cities of the 1st user.